# creating complex messages with nested structure

Tags: python, ros2

I am trying to publish topic with dictionary inside dictionary.I wanted to publish a topic from from one node to another as message given below.

```
> {frame:
    {frameheader:
            {time:3,frame_number:402}},
     {framebody:
           {power:290,voltage:45,speed:789}}
```

.

Can you help how will be custom .msg file format and how will i use it in my node.(importing and using that nested structure)
Now I am coverting it into string before publishing and then decode.

Answer (score 2):

In ROS the message definitions are not dictionaries, they are objects and the attributes of that object correspond to the "key" within the message definition.

In case you want to map the content of a dictionary to a message definition you can do it in the following way, but keep in mind that the "key" of the dictionary must exist and have the same name as in the message definition.

```py
class MsgTest:
    # this emulate the message definition
    power = 0
    voltage = 0
    speed = 0

msgTest = MsgTest()

test_dict = {
    "power":290,
    "voltage":45,
    "speed":789
}

for key, value in test_dict.items():
    # check if the attr exist in the message definition
    if hasattr(msgTest, key):
        setattr(msgTest, key, value )
```

Regarding how to create your own message definition the best place to check is the documentation [Create custom msg and srv files](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html)

I hope this answer sheds some light on your question.

Answer (score 2):

Almost everything you're describing here is outlined in [the documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries.html), so I would recommend starting there. But, I've outlined two options below.

---

If you can make the assumption that your message format is unchanging, then this is a pretty standard messages use-case: you declare a message for each level of nesting and construct a new message from that. In your case, that would mean creating a `frameheader.msg`:

```
int32 time
int32 frame_number
```

and a `framebody.msg`:

```
int32 power
int32 voltage
int32 speed
```

You can then use those custom messages to create a new custom `frame.msg` message:

```
frameheader header
framebody body
```

When building, these `.msg` files are converted to Python, C++, etc objects that you can access, e.g.,:

```
f = frame()
f.header.time = 1
f.body.voltage = 2
```

(I've assumed here that you're using integers but that may or may not be the case).

---

So that's the standard way of doing things. In your case, though, you've mentioned that you're decoding/encoding. I would recommend against this if you can help it: a static defined message offers a lot of stability and interoperability that you don't get with on-the-fly dictionaries. But, if it's unavoidable, you could have a message that contains only a string. For simplicity I'll use `String` from `std_msgs`, but the docs do recommend you making a custom message rather than using these off-the-shelf.

So after that import (`from std_msgs.msg import String`) you could create a node with a publisher, and then construct a string to publish. Rather than encode/decode this by hand, the `json` library would be a big help here:

```
msg = String()
msg.data = json.dumps(my_dict_object)
self.publisher_.publish(msg)
```

On the receiving end, you can create a subscriber and access the data using a callback:

```
def listener_callback(self, msg):
    msg_data = msg.data
    my_dict_object = json.loads(msg_data)
```

Comment: I want to emphasize that serializing data into strings is strongly discouraged!

Comment: How will I publish list inside dictionary. Data inside list is also a dictionary. The type of message to be published given here                                                                                                               
  {frameheader:{time:23, number:2},framebody:[{x_size: 1, ysize: 2},{x_size: 23, ysize: 12}]}

Comment: @RosemolThomas It sounds like a dictionary, or list of dictionaries, isn't necessary here. ROS messages support array types, so this functionality is already implemented in messages. If you use the existing message format (as discussed in the documentation I linked) you should find that everything you need exists and is much easier to use than manual parsing.